# How to make Perl XML::XPath allow queries without namespace prefixes?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I'm trying to use XML::XPath to extract content from XML documents.  The documents are specified with namespaces, but I want to use XPath expressions without namespaces.  As far as I can tell, I had this working perfectly fine in two different scripts.

It seems like sometime today, the behavior of XML::XPath has changed with respect to this.  I don't see what I could have changed that has made this behavior change.

I can get some manual tests to work, if I almost fully specify namespaces, using a call to "set_namespace()" in the script (hardcoding the prefix I expect to use) and specifying the prefix in the XPath expression.

Again, I'm pretty sure I had this working yesterday, without calling "set_namespace()" in the script, or specifying prefixes in the XPath expressions.

If I don't add that "set_namespace()" call and specify prefixes in the expression, I just get empty nodesets from my queries.

I tried setting "$XML::XPath::Namespaces" to zero before I create the first XPath object, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

The following is a simple script I pipe XML into:

```
#! /bin/perl
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;
use Getopt::Long;

$| = 1;

my $opt_file;
GetOptions("f|file=s" => \$opt_file);

$XML::XPath::Namespaces = 0;

my $xpath;
if ($opt_file ne '') {
    $xpath = XML::XPath->new(filename => $opt_file);
}
else {
    $xpath = XML::XPath->new(ioref => \*STDIN);
}

while (my $expr = shift @ARGV) {
    my $nodeset = $xpath->find($expr);
    if ($nodeset) {
        if ($opt_file ne '') {
            print $opt_file . ":\n";
        }
        my $node;
        for $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
            print $node->string_value() . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample command line:

```
% echo "<ns3:abc xmlns:ns3=\"xxx\"><ns3:def>ghi</ns3:def></ns3:abc>" | xpathtext "//def"
```

I would hope to get "ghi" from this, but I'm currently getting nothing.

Comment: `ghi` is not valid XML, and even if it was, `//def` would never match the entire XML document. Please fix.

Comment: By the way, you should *always* use `use strict; use warnings;`. (`$opt_file ne ''` should be `defined($opt_file)`)

Comment: I moved the sample command line into a code block, so you can see it now.  I also added the two "use" clauses and changed the $opt_file reference.  Those didn't change the result, but I don't think either of us would have expected that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that module is buggy.

Let's forget about your question for a minute and use `$XML::XPath::Namespaces=1;` (the default) for now.

1. ```
   $ perl -E'say q{<r><e>E</e></r>}' |
      xpathtext //e
   E
   ```

   Correct. There is an `e` element in the null namespace.
2. ```
   $ perl -E'say q{<r xmlns:p="http://n"><p:e>E</p:e></r>}' |
      xpathtext //e
   [nothing]
   ```

   Correct. There are no `e` elements in the null namespace.
3. ```
   $ perl -E'say q{<r xmlns="http://n"><e>E</e></r>}' |
      xpathtext //e
   E
   ```

   Incorrect. There are no `e` elements in the null namespace, but one was printed.
4. ```
   $ perl -E'say q{<r><e xmlns="http://n">E</e></r>}' |
      xpathtext //e
   E
   ```

   Incorrect. There are no `e` elements in the null namespace, but one was printed.
5. ```
   $ perl -E'say q{<r xmlns:p="http://n"><p:e>E</p:e></r>}' |
      xpathtext //p:e
   E
   ```

   Incorrect. This should be an error as there's no way of knowing whether `p` in the XPath refers to the `http://n` namespace or not.
6. ```
   $ perl -E'say q{<r xmlns="http://n"><e>E</e></r>}' |
      xpathtext //p:e
   [nothing]
   ```

   Incorrect. This should be an error as there's no way of knowing whether `p` in the XPath refers to the `http://n` namespace or not.

Given this level of bugginess, it's no surprise you're having problems.

---

Now let's find out what `$XML::XPath::Namespace=0;` does.

After rerunning the above programs with `$XML::XPath::Namespaces=0;`, we find that the answer is "absolutely nothing".

I've confirmed this by attaching magic to the variable. The variable is never used (in the latest version, XML-XPath-1.13)!

So the module half does what you want, and half does what it should with no apparent means of customising it.